# How to differentiate TE and TM mode with AMZI in this article

Tags: quantum-information

I am looking some papers on quantum key distribution and there is an article based on BB84 phase coding. I am unable to understand how it is possible for them to associate TE and TM mode with different phase. Can anyone help me?

The random polarization rotation, together with suitable birefringence
in Bob’s AMZI (asymmetric Mach-Zehnder interferometer), provided an effective random basis selection for measurement, where the birefringence was temperature-controlled so that the transverse electric (TE) and transverse magnetic (TM) modes corresponded to the X and Y bases in the phase coding scheme, respectively.

> [image]
>
> Source: Quantum key distribution over 120km using ultrahigh purity single photon source and superocnducting single photon detector. K. Takemoto et al, [*Sci. Rep.* **5**, 14383 (2015)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/srep14383).

Answer (score 0):

In a [Mach-Zehnder interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-Zehnder_interferometer), the relative phase acquired by the two arms of the interferometer determines, via constructive vs destructive interference, which output port will carry the signal.

As an example, in normal operation, the interferometer might be balanced such that there is complete destructive interference on output port 1, resulting in all of the signal being routed to output port 2 through constructive interference. If you then change this, by adding a phase of $\pi$ to one of the arms, then you'll switch constructive interference to destructive, and vice versa, and you'll route all of the signal energy to the output port 1 instead.

In this configuration, there is a birefringent element in one of the arms, which means that the two different polarizations will acquire different phase differences over the interferometer; if you balance things correctly, this will have the effect of separating the two polarizations out to the two output ports. This is the entire point of [birefringence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) - different polarizations observe different refractive indices, and therefore acquire phase at different rates. The Mach-Zehnder interferometer is there to translate that difference in phase into a difference in path.

Now, you could also achieve this with a polarizing beam splitter, but their setup is also switchable: the temperature control over the birefringent element allows them to alter the phase difference for the two polarizations, and therefore change the assignment of which signal goes where. This is also an over-complicated solution (you could make the switch with e.g. a half-wave plate before the beam splitter), but the point is that the temperature-controlled switch is *fast*, which they need to do in order to make the choices and detections on the Alice and Bob sides to be spatially separated from each other.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, it seems what happened there isn't as you explained. As the TE and TM mode are not separated into two different paths, they are directed into a same out-arm of AMZI. You may notice the bit "0" in the upper out-port, 1 in the bottom.

Comment: @DieJie I wish you good luck finding someone to provide whatever information you feel is missing.